# move menu scrollbar to right or scroll only in the menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
$(function() {
  "use strict";
  $(".navbar-toggler").on("click", function() {
    $(".navbar-toggler").toggleClass("collapsed");
    $(".offcanvas-collapse").toggleClass("open");
    let menuposition = $("#toggler").offset().left + $("#toggler").width() + 55;
    let windowsize = $(window).width();
    let offcanvas = windowsize - menuposition;
    let fromtop = $("#navigation").height() + 16;
    $(".offcanvas-collapse").css("right", offcanvas);
    $(".offcanvas-collapse").css("top", fromtop);
    $("body").toggleClass("off-canvas-active");
    if (!$(".navbar-brand").hasClass("makeappear")) {
      $(".navbar-brand").addClass("makeappear");
    }
    if ($("body").hasClass("off-canvas-active")) {
      $("html").addClass("no-scroll");
    } else {
      $("html").removeClass("no-scroll");
    }
  });

  $(".off-canvas-overlay").on("click", function() {
    $(".navbar-toggler").toggleClass("collapsed");
    $(".offcanvas-collapse").toggleClass("open");
    $("body").toggleClass("off-canvas-active");
    if ($("body").hasClass("off-canvas-active")) {
      $("body").addClass("nav-open");
    } else {
      $("body").removeClass("nav-open");
    }
    if ($("body").hasClass("off-canvas-active")) {
      $("html").addClass("no-scroll");
    } else {
      $("html").removeClass("no-scroll");
    }
  });


  
});
```

```css
.navbar-nav li .nav-link {
  padding-right: .5rem;
  padding-left: .5rem;
}
#navbarCollapse li.active {
  background-color: #BA122B;
}
#navbarCollapse li.active a {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #BA122B;
}

#navbarCollapse .menu {
  padding-top: 30px;
}
#navbarCollapse .dropdown-menu {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
#navbarCollapse li a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E3E3E3;
  color: #BA122B;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: color, background-color;
  transition-property: color, background-color;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
}
#navbarCollapse li a:hover {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #BA122B;
}
#navbarCollapse parent:after {

}
.body {
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding-top: 2rem;
}

.off-canvas-active .off-canvas-overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
.off-canvas-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  z-index: 1000;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
 
}
.offcanvas-collapse.open {

  display: block;
  -webkit-animation: slide-right .3s ease-out;
    -moz-animation: slide-right .3s ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slide-right {
      0% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); }
    100% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateX(0); }
}
@-moz-keyframes slide-right {
      0% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateX(-100%); }
    100% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateX(0); }
}
.offcanvas-collapse {
  position: fixed;
  top: 56px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 270px;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transition-duration: .3s;
  transition-property: width;
  display: none;
  overflow-y:auto;
}
.navbar-expand-md .navbar-toggler {
  display: block!important;
}

.navbar-toggler {
  border: none;
  height: 40px;
}
.navbar-toggler:active, .navbar-toggler:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
.navbar-toggler .icon-bar {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 2px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  background-color: #BA122B;
}
.navbar-dark .navbar-toggler .icon-bar {
  background: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-toggler .icon-bar:nth-of-type(1) {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(2px, 2px);
}
.navbar-toggler .icon-bar:nth-of-type(2) {
  opacity: 0;
}
.navbar-toggler .icon-bar:nth-of-type(3) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(1px, -1px);
}
.navbar-toggler.collapsed .icon-bar {
  margin: 5px auto;
  transform: none;
  opacity: 1;
}
.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.dropdown-toggle::after {
  right: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}
.nav-open {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.no-scroll {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body class="site">
<nav id="navigation" class="navbar fixed-top navbar-white bg-white border-bottom shadow-sm">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        </a>
        <button id="toggler" class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="offcanvas-collapse border-left shadow-sm bg-white" id="navbarCollapse">
          <ul class="nav menu navbar-nav ml-auto text-uppercase mod-list">
<li class="item-102 default current active"><a href="/demo/" class=" nav-link">Welcome!</a></li><li class="item-103 deeper parent dropdown"><a href="#" title="#pageSubmenu" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" "="">testing</a><ul class="nav-child unstyled small dropdown-menu"><li class="item-110"><a href="#" class="nav-link">level 2</a></li></ul></li><li class="item-104 deeper parent dropdown"><a href="/demo/aasssssssssssssssssssssss-2" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" "="">testing</a><ul class="nav-child unstyled small dropdown-menu"><li class="item-111"><a href="#" class="nav-link">level 3</a></li></ul></li><li class="item-105"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li><li class="item-106"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li><li class="item-107"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li><li class="item-108"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li><li class="item-109"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li><li class="item-102 default current active"><a href="/demo/" class=" nav-link">Welcome!</a></li><li class="item-103 deeper parent dropdown"><a href="#" title="#pageSubmenu" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" "="">testing</a><ul class="nav-child unstyled small dropdown-menu"><li class="item-110"><a href="#" class="nav-link">level 2</a></li></ul></li><li class="item-104 deeper parent dropdown"><a href="/demo/aasssssssssssssssssssssss-2" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" "="">testing</a><ul class="nav-child unstyled small dropdown-menu"><li class="item-111"><a href="#" class="nav-link">level 3</a></li></ul></li><li class="item-105"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li><li class="item-106"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li><li class="item-107"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li><li class="item-108"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li><li class="item-109"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li><li class="item-102 default current active"><a href="/demo/" class=" nav-link">Welcome!</a></li><li class="item-103 deeper parent dropdown"><a href="#" title="#pageSubmenu" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" "="">testing</a><ul class="nav-child unstyled small dropdown-menu"><li class="item-110"><a href="#" class="nav-link">level 2</a></li></ul></li><li class="item-104 deeper parent dropdown"><a href="/demo/aasssssssssssssssssssssss-2" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" "="">testing</a><ul class="nav-child unstyled small dropdown-menu"><li class="item-111"><a href="#" class="nav-link">level 3</a></li></ul></li><li class="item-105"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li><li class="item-106"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li><li class="item-107"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li><li class="item-108"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li><li class="item-109"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li><li class="item-102 default current active"><a href="/demo/" class=" nav-link">Welcome!</a></li><li class="item-103 deeper parent dropdown"><a href="#" title="#pageSubmenu" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" "="">testing</a><ul class="nav-child unstyled small dropdown-menu"><li class="item-110"><a href="#" class="nav-link">level 2</a></li></ul></li><li class="item-104 deeper parent dropdown"><a href="/demo/aasssssssssssssssssssssss-2" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" "="">testing</a><ul class="nav-child unstyled small dropdown-menu"><li class="item-111"><a href="#" class="nav-link">level 3</a></li></ul></li><li class="item-105"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li><li class="item-106"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li><li class="item-107"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li><li class="item-108"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li><li class="item-109"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li></ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
<div class="off-canvas-overlay"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have created an offcanvas menu what is activated by click. I want to disable body/html scrolling when the menu is active, and activate the scrollbar on the menu.

On the Capture I disabled the scrolling on body/html and and enabled on the menu, its posible to move the scrollbar to the right?

Or with javascript/jquery disable the scrolling on body and enable scrolling for the menu?

If you have any other idea achieving this please share :)

[image: capture]

Comment: Could you please share your code?

Comment: @CristianoSoares I added the snippet to my post

Comment: it might have something to do with your `overflow` properties. I would check them.

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like your example was almost there, it just had one error in the CSS related to scrolling that needed to be adjusted.

Your JS was adding the `no-scroll` class to the `html` element correctly. However, the `.no-scroll` class in your CSS had the `overflow-y` property set to `scroll` and not `hidden`. The `hidden` value is what prevents the scrollbar from showing when there is content that goes beyond the height of the element it is attached to.

Let me know if I misunderstood your question or if you have any questions related to what I adjusted.

```js
$(function() {
  "use strict";
  $(".navbar-toggler").on("click", function() {
    $(".navbar-toggler").toggleClass("collapsed");
    $(".offcanvas-collapse").toggleClass("open");
    let menuposition = $("#toggler").offset().left + $("#toggler").width() + 55;
    let windowsize = $(window).width();
    let offcanvas = windowsize - menuposition;
    let fromtop = $("#navigation").height() + 16;
    $(".offcanvas-collapse").css("right", offcanvas);
    $(".offcanvas-collapse").css("top", fromtop);
    $("body").toggleClass("off-canvas-active");
    if (!$(".navbar-brand").hasClass("makeappear")) {
      $(".navbar-brand").addClass("makeappear");
    }
    if ($("body").hasClass("off-canvas-active")) {
      $("html").addClass("no-scroll");
    } else {
      $("html").removeClass("no-scroll");
    }
  });

  $(".off-canvas-overlay").on("click", function() {
    $(".navbar-toggler").toggleClass("collapsed");
    $(".offcanvas-collapse").toggleClass("open");
    $("body").toggleClass("off-canvas-active");
    if ($("body").hasClass("off-canvas-active")) {
      $("body").addClass("nav-open");
    } else {
      $("body").removeClass("nav-open");
    }
    if ($("body").hasClass("off-canvas-active")) {
      $("html").addClass("no-scroll");
    } else {
      $("html").removeClass("no-scroll");
    }
  });



});
```

```css
.navbar-nav li .nav-link {
  padding-right: .5rem;
  padding-left: .5rem;
}

#navbarCollapse li.active {
  background-color: #BA122B;
}

#navbarCollapse li.active a {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #BA122B;
}

#navbarCollapse .menu {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

#navbarCollapse .dropdown-menu {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

#navbarCollapse li a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E3E3E3;
  color: #BA122B;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: color, background-color;
  transition-property: color, background-color;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
}

#navbarCollapse li a:hover {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #BA122B;
}

#navbarCollapse parent:after {}

.body {
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding-top: 2rem;
}

.off-canvas-active .off-canvas-overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.off-canvas-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  z-index: 1000;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}

.offcanvas-collapse.open {
  display: block;
  -webkit-animation: slide-right .3s ease-out;
  -moz-animation: slide-right .3s ease-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide-right {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes slide-right {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

.offcanvas-collapse {
  position: fixed;
  top: 56px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 270px;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transition-duration: .3s;
  transition-property: width;
  display: none;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.navbar-expand-md .navbar-toggler {
  display: block!important;
}

.navbar-toggler {
  border: none;
  height: 40px;
}

.navbar-toggler:active,
.navbar-toggler:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.navbar-toggler .icon-bar {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 2px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  background-color: #BA122B;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-toggler .icon-bar {
  background: #ffffff;
}

.navbar-toggler .icon-bar:nth-of-type(1) {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(2px, 2px);
}

.navbar-toggler .icon-bar:nth-of-type(2) {
  opacity: 0;
}

.navbar-toggler .icon-bar:nth-of-type(3) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(1px, -1px);
}

.navbar-toggler.collapsed .icon-bar {
  margin: 5px auto;
  transform: none;
  opacity: 1;
}

.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
  right: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}

.nav-open {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.no-scroll {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden; /* Switched `scroll` to `hidden` */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body class="site">
<nav id="navigation" class="navbar fixed-top navbar-white bg-white border-bottom shadow-sm">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        </a>
        <button id="toggler" class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="offcanvas-collapse border-left shadow-sm bg-white" id="navbarCollapse">
          <ul class="nav menu navbar-nav ml-auto text-uppercase mod-list">
<li class="item-102 default current active"><a href="/demo/" class=" nav-link">Welcome!</a></li><li class="item-103 deeper parent dropdown"><a href="#" title="#pageSubmenu" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" "="">testing</a><ul class="nav-child unstyled small dropdown-menu"><li class="item-110"><a href="#" class="nav-link">level 2</a></li></ul></li><li class="item-104 deeper parent dropdown"><a href="/demo/aasssssssssssssssssssssss-2" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" "="">testing</a><ul class="nav-child unstyled small dropdown-menu"><li class="item-111"><a href="#" class="nav-link">level 3</a></li></ul></li><li class="item-105"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li><li class="item-106"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li><li class="item-107"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li><li class="item-108"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li><li class="item-109"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li><li class="item-102 default current active"><a href="/demo/" class=" nav-link">Welcome!</a></li><li class="item-103 deeper parent dropdown"><a href="#" title="#pageSubmenu" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" "="">testing</a><ul class="nav-child unstyled small dropdown-menu"><li class="item-110"><a href="#" class="nav-link">level 2</a></li></ul></li><li class="item-104 deeper parent dropdown"><a href="/demo/aasssssssssssssssssssssss-2" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" "="">testing</a><ul class="nav-child unstyled small dropdown-menu"><li class="item-111"><a href="#" class="nav-link">level 3</a></li></ul></li><li class="item-105"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li><li class="item-106"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li><li class="item-107"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li><li class="item-108"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li><li class="item-109"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li><li class="item-102 default current active"><a href="/demo/" class=" nav-link">Welcome!</a></li><li class="item-103 deeper parent dropdown"><a href="#" title="#pageSubmenu" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" "="">testing</a><ul class="nav-child unstyled small dropdown-menu"><li class="item-110"><a href="#" class="nav-link">level 2</a></li></ul></li><li class="item-104 deeper parent dropdown"><a href="/demo/aasssssssssssssssssssssss-2" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" "="">testing</a><ul class="nav-child unstyled small dropdown-menu"><li class="item-111"><a href="#" class="nav-link">level 3</a></li></ul></li><li class="item-105"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li><li class="item-106"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li><li class="item-107"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li><li class="item-108"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li><li class="item-109"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li><li class="item-102 default current active"><a href="/demo/" class=" nav-link">Welcome!</a></li><li class="item-103 deeper parent dropdown"><a href="#" title="#pageSubmenu" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" "="">testing</a><ul class="nav-child unstyled small dropdown-menu"><li class="item-110"><a href="#" class="nav-link">level 2</a></li></ul></li><li class="item-104 deeper parent dropdown"><a href="/demo/aasssssssssssssssssssssss-2" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" "="">testing</a><ul class="nav-child unstyled small dropdown-menu"><li class="item-111"><a href="#" class="nav-link">level 3</a></li></ul></li><li class="item-105"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li><li class="item-106"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li><li class="item-107"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li><li class="item-108"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li><li class="item-109"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li></ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
<div class="off-canvas-overlay"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

### Edit:

Per your comment, I've adjusted the format. The way that Bootstrap handles its modals and their scrollbars is by making the overlay fullpage and allowing that to scroll vertically, rather than just the menu inside of the modal scrolling.

Here's the adjusted snippet:

```js
$(function() {
  "use strict";
  $(".navbar-toggler").on("click", function() {
    $(".navbar-toggler").toggleClass("collapsed");
    $(".offcanvas-collapse").toggleClass("open");
    let menuposition = $("#toggler").offset().left + $("#toggler").width() + 55;
    let windowsize = $(window).width();
    let offcanvas = windowsize - menuposition;
    let fromtop = $("#navigation").height() + 16;
    // $(".offcanvas-collapse").css("right", offcanvas);
    $(".offcanvas-collapse").css("top", fromtop);
    $("body").toggleClass("off-canvas-active");
    if (!$(".navbar-brand").hasClass("makeappear")) {
      $(".navbar-brand").addClass("makeappear");
    }
    if ($("body").hasClass("off-canvas-active")) {
      $("html").addClass("no-scroll");
    } else {
      $("html").removeClass("no-scroll");
    }
  });

  $(".off-canvas-overlay").on("click", function() {
    $(".navbar-toggler").toggleClass("collapsed");
    $(".offcanvas-collapse").toggleClass("open");
    $("body").toggleClass("off-canvas-active");
    if ($("body").hasClass("off-canvas-active")) {
      $("body").addClass("nav-open");
    } else {
      $("body").removeClass("nav-open");
    }
    if ($("body").hasClass("off-canvas-active")) {
      $("html").addClass("no-scroll");
    } else {
      $("html").removeClass("no-scroll");
    }
  });



});
```

```css
.navbar-nav li .nav-link {
  padding-right: .5rem;
  padding-left: .5rem;
}

#navbarCollapse li.active {
  background-color: #BA122B;
}

#navbarCollapse li.active a {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #BA122B;
}

#navbarCollapse .menu {
  padding-top: 30px;
   width: 270px; /* Set the fixed width in the menu itself */
   margin-right: 50px; /* Add some spacing between the right side and the menu */
}

#navbarCollapse .dropdown-menu {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

#navbarCollapse li a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E3E3E3;
  color: #BA122B;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: color, background-color;
  transition-property: color, background-color;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
}

#navbarCollapse li a:hover {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #BA122B;
}

#navbarCollapse parent:after {}

.body {
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding-top: 2rem;
}

.off-canvas-active .off-canvas-overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.off-canvas-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; /* Set the overlay to take up the entire page */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  z-index: 1000;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}

.offcanvas-collapse.open {
  display: block;
  -webkit-animation: slide-right .3s ease-out;
  -moz-animation: slide-right .3s ease-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide-right {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes slide-right {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

.offcanvas-collapse {
  position: fixed;
  top: 56px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transition-duration: .3s;
  transition-property: width;
  display: none;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar-expand-md .navbar-toggler {
  display: block!important;
}

.navbar-toggler {
  border: none;
  height: 40px;
}

.navbar-toggler:active,
.navbar-toggler:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.navbar-toggler .icon-bar {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 2px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  background-color: #BA122B;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-toggler .icon-bar {
  background: #ffffff;
}

.navbar-toggler .icon-bar:nth-of-type(1) {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(2px, 2px);
}

.navbar-toggler .icon-bar:nth-of-type(2) {
  opacity: 0;
}

.navbar-toggler .icon-bar:nth-of-type(3) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(1px, -1px);
}

.navbar-toggler.collapsed .icon-bar {
  margin: 5px auto;
  transform: none;
  opacity: 1;
}

.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
  right: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}

.nav-open {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.no-scroll {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  /* Switched `scroll` to `hidden` */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body class="site">
  <nav id="navigation" class="navbar fixed-top navbar-white bg-white border-bottom shadow-sm">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      </a>
      <button id="toggler" class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      <div class="offcanvas-collapse border-left shadow-sm" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="nav menu navbar-nav ml-auto text-uppercase mod-list bg-white">
          <li class="item-102 default current active"><a href="/demo/" class=" nav-link">Welcome!</a></li>
          <li class="item-103 deeper parent dropdown"><a href="#" title="#pageSubmenu" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" "=" ">testing</a><ul class="nav-child unstyled small dropdown-menu "><li class="item-110 "><a href="# " class="nav-link
              ">level 2</a></li></ul></li><li class="item-104 deeper parent dropdown "><a href="/demo/aasssssssssssssssssssssss-2 " class="nav-link dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown " aria-expanded="false " "="">testing</a>
            <ul class="nav-child unstyled small dropdown-menu">
              <li class="item-111"><a href="#" class="nav-link">level 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="item-105"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li>
          <li class="item-106"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li>
          <li class="item-107"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li>
          <li class="item-108"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li>
          <li class="item-109"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li>
          <li class="item-102 default current active"><a href="/demo/" class=" nav-link">Welcome!</a></li>
          <li class="item-103 deeper parent dropdown"><a href="#" title="#pageSubmenu" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" "=" ">testing</a><ul class="nav-child unstyled small dropdown-menu "><li class="item-110 "><a href="# " class="nav-link
              ">level 2</a></li></ul></li><li class="item-104 deeper parent dropdown "><a href="/demo/aasssssssssssssssssssssss-2 " class="nav-link dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown " aria-expanded="false " "="">testing</a>
            <ul class="nav-child unstyled small dropdown-menu">
              <li class="item-111"><a href="#" class="nav-link">level 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="item-105"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li>
          <li class="item-106"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li>
          <li class="item-107"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li>
          <li class="item-108"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li>
          <li class="item-109"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li>
          <li class="item-102 default current active"><a href="/demo/" class=" nav-link">Welcome!</a></li>
          <li class="item-103 deeper parent dropdown"><a href="#" title="#pageSubmenu" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" "=" ">testing</a><ul class="nav-child unstyled small dropdown-menu "><li class="item-110 "><a href="# " class="nav-link
              ">level 2</a></li></ul></li><li class="item-104 deeper parent dropdown "><a href="/demo/aasssssssssssssssssssssss-2 " class="nav-link dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown " aria-expanded="false " "="">testing</a>
            <ul class="nav-child unstyled small dropdown-menu">
              <li class="item-111"><a href="#" class="nav-link">level 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="item-105"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li>
          <li class="item-106"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li>
          <li class="item-107"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li>
          <li class="item-108"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li>
          <li class="item-109"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li>
          <li class="item-102 default current active"><a href="/demo/" class=" nav-link">Welcome!</a></li>
          <li class="item-103 deeper parent dropdown"><a href="#" title="#pageSubmenu" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" "=" ">testing</a><ul class="nav-child unstyled small dropdown-menu "><li class="item-110 "><a href="# " class="nav-link
              ">level 2</a></li></ul></li><li class="item-104 deeper parent dropdown "><a href="/demo/aasssssssssssssssssssssss-2 " class="nav-link dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown " aria-expanded="false " "="">testing</a>
            <ul class="nav-child unstyled small dropdown-menu">
              <li class="item-111"><a href="#" class="nav-link">level 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="item-105"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li>
          <li class="item-106"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li>
          <li class="item-107"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li>
          <li class="item-108"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li>
          <li class="item-109"><a href="#" class="nav-link">testing</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="off-canvas-overlay"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I know that, but I want that the menu scrollbar to shows up on the right main scrollbar, I got an example in bootstrap:[link] (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/modal/#scrolling-long-content) when you click on modal, the scrollbar on the right will be active, I want the same thing

Comment: Sorry about the delay. I see what you mean though, I've adjusted my answer to add another snippet that should do what you're talking about.

Comment: Meanwhile I resolved, like in the bootstrap example, in your edited answer the menu is not positioned correct, I created a wrapper div: .offcanvas-collapse-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  z-index: 1029;
  pointer-events: none;
} then the: .offcanvas-collapse .menu-body {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  width: 270px;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transition-duration: .3s;
  transition-property: width;
  display: none;
  min-height: 100vh;
  pointer-events: all;
}